# Can I work on MVC 4 using Visual Studio 15 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can I work on old ASP.NET MVC 4 projects using Visual Studio 15 Preview? If so, would VS 15 update the project/project file?

I don't want to mess up my old projects by opening them in VS 15.

Comment: are you using some version control system? you can easily open your project and then revert any local changes if you don't like them.

Comment: Yes, we're using Visual Studio Online. Just want to make sure I can work on old MVC 4 projects as well as new ASP.NET Core projects using Visual Studio 15 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

At least you cannot do so in Visual Studio 2017 RC, but Microsoft seems to indicate the RTM release will support MVC 4,

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

> MVC 4 Projects are not supported
>
> Issue:
>
> Open MVC 4 project using Visual Studio 2017 RC prompts to Install
>   Missing Features - .NET Desktop Development, which is incorrect. Even
>   after you install the missing features, project does not load in
>   Solution Explorer and shows up as incompatible.
>
> Workaround:
>
> No workaround, support will be added in the future.

But you should consider seriously about upgrading to MVC 5, as Microsoft technical support team should requires that based on the support policies,

https://www.asp.net/support